# How to get Username from Channel name via youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know a youtuber, his name is "Hoggy". But when I find "Hoggy" on youtube, I find this. https://www.youtube.com/user/HoggyCZ

The name is the same, but the "Username" in URL is different "HoggyCZ".

Is it possible to convert the youtuber name/channel name to Username via youtube API?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the youtuber name/channel name to Username"?

Comment: i tried to explain it:  https://www.youtube.com/user/HoggyCZ  When you look on this URL, I have only the name "Hoggy" but the Username is "HoggyCZ".

Comment: If the channel is big enough, he can request a custom name. However, the legacy name "HoggyCZ" will always be there in the background. If you are writing your own page and script for loading his page, you can do it in code in the background. But that will only work for a dedicated link to him on your own page.

Comment: But the question is I only have the names, i.e. "Hoggy" here. And I want to get the URL/channel name, i.e. "HoggyCZ" automaticaly.